# installing googale (גוגלה) children's website on ubuntu

Tags: pipelight, moonlight, hebrew, education

[Googale](https://galeli.com/StudentLogin.Web) (גוגלה) is a Hebrew children's educational website designed for pre-K ages (4-5).

It is currently based on Microsoft Silverlight 5.1 technology.

Since Chrome and Firefox have recently discontinued their support in npapi plugins, Silverlight being one of them, Googale does not run out of the box on Ubuntu.

Has anyone been able to get it to work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

Two evenings of research, trial and error, led me to get it running on my Ubuntu.

If you want to get it running on Ubuntu you would have to follow these steps.

**Please note** that I tested it only on my box which is Ubuntu 16.04

1. install [Firefox Extended Support Release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/) that can the Silverlight plugin

   1.1 To prevent your all this hard work from being viciously reverted by firefox-ESR being updated automatically and replace with a *regular* firefox that can't run silverlight, I recommend *hold*ing the firefox version thus preventing the package manage from updating firefox. see more at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold firefox
   ```
2. install pipelight and Microsoft font packages. The font package is needed to display Hebrew fonts, specifically Arial.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   sudo pipelight-plugin --update
   ```
3. enable Silverlight

   ```
   sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight #Agree to licensing, but DO NOT touch wininit
   sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins #In case you don't see the Wine dialogs
   ```

   If all went well, you should see some prompts about Wine downloading and installing Silverlight 5.1 when you start Firefox. But you're not done yet. Do the following to refresh the plugin database, since at least in my experience, Silverlight does not show in Firefox right away;

   - Go to `about:support` and open your profile directory.
   - exit your browser
   - delete from your profile directory `pluginreg.dat`

   See more at [this community post about pipelight](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/enabling-silverlight-in-firefox/6908)
4. start firefox, go to [gogale website](https://galeli.com/StudentLogin.Web) and enjoy

Comment: You should add that the Pipelight PPA is for 16.04 and older only. It seems it won't be updated.